# Nothing happens when execute gulp in file.bat using VB.NET

Tags: node.js, vb.net, batch-file, iis, gulp

I try to execute gulpfile.js in file.bat using VB.NET; However, nothing happens (no error, no warning) when I debug or run file.bat.

It only works after I double click file.bat. This is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('D:/Projects/NailsuperStore_Responsive/node_modules/gulp');
var minifyCss = require('D:/Projects/NailsuperStore_Responsive/node_modules/gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('D:/Projects/NailsuperStore_Responsive/node_modules/gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default',['minify-css', 'minify-js']);
gulp.task('minify-css', function(){
  return gulp.src('../../theme/css/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCss({compatility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../theme/css'));
});
gulp.task('minify-js', function(){
  return gulp.src('../*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
});
```

My minifyCSS_JS.bat:

```
d:
cd D:\Projects\NailsuperStore_Responsive\Website\includes\scripts\nodeJS
gulp
PAUSE
```

Finally, VB.NET:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("D:\Projects\NailsuperStore_Responsive\Website\Bin\minifyCSS_JS.bat")
psi.RedirectStandardError = True
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
psi.CreateNoWindow = False
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
psi.UseShellExecute = False
Dim process As Process = process.Start(psi)
```

I researched a long time and I think my problems in IIS server, just like I don't have admin permission to turn on command prompt.
Please help me.
Thanks